# How can I prevent a Template from re-rendering every element in a {{#each}} block?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, blaze

Suppose I have a template that fetches an array from the cloud... or something. Then I render each element in that array using another template, like so:

```html
<template name='A'>
  {{> B data=cloudData}} <!-- [{foo:'4142'}, {foo:'af3d'}, ...] -->
</template>

<template name='B'>
  {{#each data}}
    {{> C}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I expect cloudData to change often. Is Meteor/Blaze smart enough to only re-render the parts of 'data' that change? If not, how can I force Meteor/Blaze to be smart about it in an idiomatic way?

Comment: From my experience blaze does a pretty good job and only updates the items that change. If you really want full control and are using meteor collections you can setup a client side observer. As items are added and removed you can add and remove the dom elements from a parent container. The oberver documentation can be found here https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges

Comment: If you want re-render control on a Template level you should use a reactive data source combined with a tracker's autorun withing the oncreated callback. However a full working solution would require a bit more code on the "cloud" side, meaning some mockup on how you expect external data to be fetched etc.

Comment: I second @Jankapunkt opinion where you'd have to use [tracker](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html) to create a custom reactive data source that you can fine tune instead of directly passing your `cloudData`.